# In First Posts, should I upvote a good-looking, well-explained answer even if I can't judge its accuracy?

Tags: discussion, first-post-review

Sometimes when reviewing First Answers I'm not sure if I should upvote the answer based solely on its structure or also on its correctness.

For example, I was reviewing some First Posts today and came with a First Answer about a quite complex JavaScript matter. Even though I couldn't evaluate if the answer was right or not, it was really well structured with many references. I ended up upvoting and, for my surprise (more or less), it was test. And I passed (yey).

But it got me thinking if this really was the correct behavior. 
I figure that a less explained right answer is more useful than a well explained wrong answer. Should I upvote a well structured answer even if I don't understand if it's indeed answering the question? Would `No Action Needed` or `Skip` be better suited options in this situation?

Comment: Skip is always better if you don't know.

Comment: @rene While that suggestion is always true, with reference to this situation, are you implying that a reviewer should skip if an answer *looks* well-presented, is on-topic, and is an answer, but they do not have the domain expertise to judge if it's correct? Being able to provide feedback on technical correctness is *useful*, but I hadn't been under the impression that it was *required*.

Comment: Also don't forget to check (at least a little bit) if that answer post isn't copied from somewhere else.

Comment: You should never vote on presentation alone, and understand that answer correctness is much more important. If you cannot tell if the answer is correct or not, ***do not vote on it***.

Comment: @CertainPerformance a reviewer should use skip if they feel like guessing ... nothing is required.

Comment: @rene Sure, but voting is optional too, which is why I was thinking that "No action required" could be acceptable (which does not require guessing, though does not provide any feedback). I suppose one could skip in the hope that a domain expert who happens to be reviewing comes across the question and can understand it enough to vote

Comment: @CertainPerformance reviewing as No Action **is** an action. If you are *not sure* if a post warrants any action or no action, Skip is your best option.

Comment: @Certain if you click "no action is required", you are saying "this can be removed from the review queue", and thus preventing other users who might be domain experts from seeing the post and voting on it, for example.

Comment: Up voting answer in the area you have no expertise (just because answer looks good) is the absolutely the worst thing you can do (inside or outside review queue).

Comment: @rene consider editing the duplicates to add canonical [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)

Comment: @gnat and that is done